# how to place menu button in iphone

Tags: iphone

i need to place menu button in iphone.

i have some touch with android.

In android i display like [this](http://d.imagehost.org/download/0406/menu) by pressing menu.

Is it possible to handle iphone menu button.

if it is not where can i place these.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are going to have to rephrase that question for me to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the round rect button and change the property into custom place the image as the background image of the button do this for more menu item in your home page.

this is the way i do the menu item.......

Answer (score 0):

I think with Xcode and Interface Builder (iPhone's development platform), getting this task done would be even simpler.

As a brief introduction to iPhone app's UI design, to place this tab bar (as you put it, the menu) on a view, all you need to do is pick up a tab bar from the library and place it on a nib file's view. You can also connect such a tab bar with some codes responsible for internal logic by simply clicking and dragging. It's simple.

btw, a nib file is just some file format Xcode and Interface Builder use to hold the UI data.

Answer (score 0):

iPhones don't have a dedicated slide out menu - everything is on the screen at all times, and there are no purpose built buttons (like back and home).

You should either always show your actions on the screen, or if they are unimportant or infrequent, hide them behind another action button (like a + or wrench icon).

Answer (score 0):

You should use images same as menu items and put custom button over the images.This is the only way to show menu as you want.

Iphone sdk provides tabBar and toolBar, you also can use these in customize forms.This is the correct way to making menu.Iphone design pattern having lot of strengths over android so you can make every thing in Iphone easily but you cant make every thing in android same as iPhone.Iphone having international standards so must use iPhone's controls.

Answer (score 0):

.h

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@property ( nonatomic , retain )  IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

-(void)AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom:(id)sender;

-(void)createMenuWithButtonSize:(CGSize)buttonSize withOffset:(CGFloat)offset noOfButtons:(int)totalNoOfButtons;
```

.m

```
@synthesize scrollView;



-(void)AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom:(id)sender{


    NSLog(@"AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom called");


    UIButton *button=(UIButton *)sender;


    if (button.tag == 0) {

        NSLog(@"hey have clicked first button, this is my tag : %i \n\n",button.tag);
    }
    else if (button.tag == 1) {

        NSLog(@"hey have clicked second button, this is my tag : %i \n\n",button.tag);

    }
    // ......like this

    NSLog(@"button clicked is : %iBut \n\n",button.tag);



}       



-(void)createMenuWithButtonSize:(CGSize)buttonSize withOffset:(CGFloat)offset noOfButtons:(int)totalNoOfButtons{

for (int i = 0; i < totalNoOfButtons; i++) {

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        //[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with image

        //OR

    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%iBut",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title

    button.frame = CGRectMake(i*(offset+buttonSize.width), 8.0, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height);

    button.clipsToBounds = YES;

    button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;

    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;//half of the width

    button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;

    button.layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    button.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;

    button.tag=i;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:button];

}

self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake((buttonSize.width + offset) * totalNoOfButtons, buttonSize.height);

    //self.navigationItem.titleView=self.scrollView;//if u have navigationcontroller then enable this line
```

}

**Dont forget to connect the scrollView in interface builder**

**while creating the scrollview in IB make sure ur scrollView height is 44.which is default to navigation bar.so it will look nice.**

```
in viewDidLoad call 

[self createMenuWithButtonSize:CGSizeMake(70.0, 30.0) withOffset:20.0f noOfButtons:30];
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]